# AngularJS: Do I need to know database structure to implement?

Tags: database, database-design, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm a beginner AngularJS user. I've been trying to pull hard coded JSON (backend and server data not ready) currently. It seems that in order to pull data, for instance when using the very common ng-repeat, I need to know the database structure (as the rendered JSON will mirror that structure, right?).

So while I can code independently of the back end, am I correct in my assumption that I must know the database structure? For instance... I might want to pull user comment data. This could be in its own database and I might do this: ng-repeat='comment in comments' and filter for the specific user within each comment entry in database. Whereas if comments are only within a user table it would be ng-repeat='comment in user[0].comments'. I would imagine the former is the correct approach but I honestly have never learned about proper database structure. It seems that it is something you must know in order to properly implement AngularJS though.

Any help is appreciated. I really want to make sure I approach things properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to (or should) know the database structure. AngularJS is an MVC framework. A basic principle in this architecture is the *separation of concerns*. Simple put: do not mix stuff, but more specifically, you're talking about the communication between two systems: a local one (the browser running angularJS) and the remote one (a server that might, or might not, be the same that served the angular files to the client)

For example, your view should not be accessing your database (if you were working with, say, PHP, you should not have things like `mysql_query(...)` in a view).

You should also design components to be loosely coupled: make them as independent as possible. Unit tests help you think that way and AngularJS is particularly unit-tests-friendly with karma. Following this principle, what if you use the twitter API to show tweets in your angularJS application? you don't need to know about the internals of twitter. There is an API that serves this JSON in a format that you can use.
Your backend should provide this (for example, with a façade controller), and you should agree with the backend team what data will be available.

Instead of making your design depend on the database structure, make the backend API depend on your requirements. this way you'll have two systems loosely coupled and the backend team can do whatever they want without affecting you. For example, changing the DBMS or the structure of the tables.

If you want to pull comments, you might have a remote call (`$http` or `ng-resource`) that gets all the comments for a specific user (or for a few users, because you might want to minimize the number of remote calls) in a service or in a controller. The server responds with a json file that represents this (and probably some more things that will be needed soon, like profile picture urls, user id's, etc). Then you put the data you want to expose to a view (a subset of what you fetched from the server) in `$scope`.

Comment: I see what you're saying with separation of concerns. That makes sense. I guess my question is the JSON structure of the call I'm making to the server. I'm currently just hardcoding JSON to develop  locally. I'd like to hard code it in the same way that it will render when called from server. So to pull that data, the comment , username and ID, profile picture, etc. There is an inherent structure that is being represented. Which I need to know when pulling into the view. So if comments pull as a list of users with their comments as a subset vs. Pulling list of comments with users as a subset.

Comment: In those two examples, the JSON would be presented differently and as such the view would be different. As I said, I suspect the main data I'm pulling, in this instance comments, should also be the table I pull, I.e. comments table (and not a user table with comments as a sunset of data). But it seems this is something I would need to know? Although perhaps it isn't really knowing database structure? Or maybe it is loosely? And as you said, back end should depend on my requirements. Hopefully I'm not being confusing.

Comment: hi @jstacks, you can hardcode the json to develop locally (or put it in a separate file and load it using `$http` or `$resource`). You have a data model in the server stored in a DB. the fact that you are fetching it with json is abstracting you from the complexity of the DBMS server-side. now, what should you include in this json file? notice that you have controllers that talk to a model (in angular ~~ client-side). you have to create this model with the data you fetch from the server. then you can render this model in as many different views as you wish.

Comment: I'm thinking of this scenario: user visits a url -> goes to a controller -> fetches data from server (if not cached) -> creates/extends a model -> angular triggers events to tell the view that data arrived -> the data is shown. if this model was stored in `$rootScope` or in a service, you can reuse the data you downloaded in other views. notice that once it is in the browser, the user can do nasty things (i.e. don't fetch things that this user should not see). the data you download should meet the needs of that transaction.

Comment: for example, you might have two remote calls (one to get a list of users, one to get a list of comments) and the controller does the business logic to merge them. or you might have one call and delegate this task to the backend so you can fetch the json in a way that helps you more. in my opinion, you should ignore the structure of the DB and send requests like myapi.com/getAllComents, myapi.com/getUserComments?userid=4, etc

Comment: Ah OK! So ultimately the data can be queried and rendered in JSON however I require it? In the case, I'll hard code JSON how I think makes most sense based on what I need in individual cases and can let the backend in proper way. Thank you for the help.